# Vectorize string operation in Python

Tags: python, string, performance, vectorization, coding-efficiency

Having two lists of strings, my goal is to apply a function `f` on cross product of these two vectors as

```
a = ['red dwarf', 'smart cat']
b = ['red car', 'black hole', 'cat'] 

[[f(x,y) for x in a] for y in b]
```

in a more efficient way.

What options are actually available for

1. a general (custom) Python function `f`
2. pre-defined string distance metric?

In 2), I am looking for something similar to `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` (distance metrics) that can be applied on strings.
In 1), I tried to look on Cython and Numba, but I was not able to perform better than the nested Python for loop - note that I tested a function

```
def f(a, b):    
    v1 =  set(a)
    v2 = set(b)
    return len(v1.intersection(v2)) / (len(v1)+len(v2))
```

Comment: There are more elegant ways to generate the `(x, y)` groupings, but none of that really helps - you still have to call a Python function `f`, and feed it Python strings. Tools like Numpy are capable of vectorization because, among other things, they have the privilege of working with raw data in a pre-determined, fixed size, and they have the privilege of working at a lower level than the Python object wrappers. More practically, you optimize this sort of thing using details of the actual `f`.

Comment: For example, for the shown `f`, you might pre-compute the `set`s first, so that you're only creating O(N) of them rather than O(N^2).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Might also be faster to not use sets but use ints, as k-bit bitsets where k is the number of different occurring characters, and use `&` for intersection and the `bit_count` method for size.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that was the question 2, if there is a `numpy`-like library that is capable to work with strings and avoids calling a Python function `f`, at least for some distance metric (e.g., a vector extension of https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein). 

Regarding the first question, I expect that the performance improvement could be possible by rewriting the loop with some optimized tool like Numba or Cython so that somehow optimized (pre-compiled) version of `f` would be executed instead. But I was not able outperform the shown solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.product` (the shape wouldn't be the same as your output though):

```
from itertools import product
out = [f(*tup) for tup in product(a,b)]
```

Or as suggested by @Andrej and @Kelly, modify `f` by mapping each list to sets first then do the operations on the sets:

```
out = [len(v1 & v2) / (len(v1) + len(v2)) for v1, v2 in product(map(set, a), map(set, b))]
```

Output:

```
[0.38461538461538464, 0.1875, 0.1, 0.3076923076923077, 0.1875, 0.3]
```

That being said, I think your approach is plenty efficient imo.

Comment: I think to speed-up one can make sets from strings first (no not make sets in each function call).

Comment: @AndrejKesely do you mean something like: `[len(x.intersection(y)) / (len(x)+len(y)) for x in map(set, a) for y in map(set, b)]`?

Comment: I mean `a = [set(s) for s in a]`, the same for `b` and then call `out = [f(*tup) for tup in product(a,b)]` (that way you don't have to call `v1 = set(a)` inside the `f()`

Comment: @AndrejKesely If you give them to `product` anyway, you could do that with `a = map(set, a)` and same for `b`.

Comment: `v1 & v2` is probably faster than `v1.intersection(v2)` (and nicer, too :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it is really nice. Even if the suggested solution improves my original one, it still suffers by calling the interpreted python function `f` in loop. Nevertheless it suggests me another possible approach how to go beyond that - use some embedding method to convert string to vector and then apply  `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` on top of that.